# Java & Hibernate project - sort by date

Tags: java, hibernate

at this code I m getting all data from my database;

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    myEntityList = (mytableDAO.GetAllOfThem());
}
```

GetAllOfThem method its like that;

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<E> GetAllOfThem() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from " + getEntityClass().getName()).list();
}
```

But **I need to get data sort by date.** I need to get firstly new one.

How can I get the sort by date? Should Am I write new sql query?

Comment: may be you can use order by function of sql?

Comment: @drgPP actually I dont understand your point. You mean, write new sql query?

Comment: my option is like gknicker answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate queries can have an `order by` clause. Add one to your query like so:

```
"from " + getEntityClass().getName() + " order by YourDateColumnName"
```

Comment: This is the answer I m looking for. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways

add 1 field "ModifiedDate" in your table
and order by ModifiedDate

```
"from " + getEntityClass().getName() + " order by ModifiedDate"
```

or you may use order By id also

```
"from " + getEntityClass().getName() + " order by getEntityClass().getId()"
```